# Write image in excel at row 3000 to 3005 in java using apache poi when using LibreOffice Calc to open file

Tags: excel, apache-poi, ubuntu-14.04, java-7, libreoffice-calc

I am using **poi 3.9** to create xlsx files everything is fine until my file length crossed **1600 rows**. After crossing 1600 rows I am able to write data but I am **unable to write images** all images get appended on each other at row number 1640 this is weird and I am working on poi from long time and picked the issue that its library limitation and updated my **poi to 3.15** but same issue, here I am able to write images up to **2000 rows** then I tried **poi 3.16** but again issue is same but here I can write Images up to **2500 rows**.
Below is my code for writing images

```
private void drawImageOnExcelSheet(XSSFSheet sitePhotosSheet, int row1,
        int row2, int col1, int col2, String fileName) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        int pictureIdx = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes,Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        is.close();
        CreationHelper helper = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

        Drawing drawing = sitePhotosSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

        anchor.setCol1(col1);
        anchor.setCol2(col2);
        anchor.setRow1(row1);
        anchor.setRow2(row2);
        drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note:** that I am able to write data but getting issue only for images. Please suggest how can I solve this issue.
Please see image below here you can see that at row 1639 two images are appended on each other and there are many images behind these two ones since my last row for images that I have printed on console is 3400.
[image]

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere than the code you have shown. Using exactly your code I am able to set pictures wherever I want. Also the shown screen shot does not fit to the code. Using that code the pictures will be anchored exactly to `col1`, `col2`, `row1`, `row2` and not shifted left and down as shown in the screen shot. To shift as shown there would must be `dx` and `dy` present in the anchor.

Comment: I have tried using template file and also tried by creating new xlsx using code but same problem. Have you tried writing image at row 3000 to 3005  becoz I am trying from 2 days and have tried in many ways. If possible show me ur report screen shot

Comment: And which version ur using for poi, try by passing row1=3000 and row2=3005 to my method if you get expected output share ur screen.

Comment: See my answer. But again, your code cannot producing the result of your screen shot since there the pictures are shifted from exact cell positions and your code does not set `dx`and/or `dy` to the anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apache poi` version 3.16 and Java 8 (I'm not a friend of ancient software versions)

Having following code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

public class ExcelDrawImage {

 private static void drawImageOnExcelSheet(XSSFSheet sitePhotosSheet, int row1,
        int row2, int col1, int col2, String fileName) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        int pictureIdx = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes,Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
        is.close();
        CreationHelper helper = sitePhotosSheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

        Drawing drawing = sitePhotosSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

        anchor.setCol1(col1);
        anchor.setCol2(col2);
        anchor.setRow1(row1);
        anchor.setRow2(row2);
        drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  for (int r = 0; r < 10000; r+=10 ) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue("Picture " + (r/10+1) + ":");
   drawImageOnExcelSheet((XSSFSheet)sheet, r+1, r+6, 1, 4, "samplePict.jpeg");
  }

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelDrawImage.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Same in Ubuntu Linux:

[image]

Result in Calc:

[image]

Comment: Hi you are correct actually I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and LibreOffice calc to open file and it produces above issue. In my case also file not showing any issue in windows do you know reason behind this.

Comment: Hm, I'm also using Ubuntu for creating the file, see my supplement. And even using Libreoffice Calc the file is fine for me. But Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; as said, I'm not a friend of ancient software.

Comment: Yes it may be due to OS issue as in my case also its working fine if I open same file in windows. Anyway thanks for support.